# In selenium can I perform getCSSValue("color") after mouse hover action

Tags: java, selenium

There is a scenario where I hover on element and then one vertical line starts showing and I want to `getCSSValue` of that element after hover.

Normally without hovering directly by using `xpath.getCSSValue("color");` is giving me color but what I want is first hover on that element then it will start showing the red color vertical line and then to take color value.

I know/tried, `getCSSValue("color")` on action class method, but action class is not allowing it.

```
public By hoverOnAccount = By.xpath("myxpath"); 
WebElement abcd = driver.findElement(hoverOnAccount);
String abc = abcd.getCssValue("color");
```

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, please also add the actions method you tried.

```
WebElement hoverElement = driver.findElement(yourElementSelector);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(hoverElement).build().perform();

hoverElement.getCSSValue("color");
```

If that one won't work you can try that action with `JavaScript Executor` :

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                    "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                    "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";


((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javaScript, hoverElement);
```

Comment: What I have done is public By hoverOnAccount = By.xpath("myxpath"); then WebElement abcd = driver.findElement(hoverOnAccount); and the String abc = abcd.getCssValue("color");. It worked. But I have one question, what does "public By XXXX" does. And why to assign that to a web element.

Comment: So, like defining a variable, you are defining By variable. @KavitaKulkarni

Comment: ah ok got it. But I guess we can not use hover and getCSSValue at same time, correct me if I am wrong.It has to be sequential.